# Android Parse Query Retrieving Columns

Tags: android, parse-platform

So this is a very basic question but I've really hit a roadblock here. I've attempted quite a few things but I can't really understand how to extract the data from my parse table and get it into my app. I went through all the tutorials and still can't connect the dots.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

[image]

I want my app to be able to display every persons name who has a `"human"` designation. I've tried the following base code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PersonClass");
    query.whereEqualTo("PersonType","human");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> personList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {                  
               ***HERE IS WHERE I"M CONFUSED ABOUT HOW TO EXTRACT THE DATA!!!!**
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

So the results I WOULD LIKE to see would be a return of `"Steve"` and `"Gary"` as they are both `human` designations

Where do I input data to point it towards searching through the specific column of `"PersonsName"` and then once it is pointed in that direction, how would I extract that data from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PersonClass");
query.whereEqualTo("PersonType","human");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

  @Override
  public void done(List<ParseObject> personList, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {    
        if(personList.size()>0 ){             
            for (ParseObject person : personList) {
                String pearsonName=person.getString("PersonsName");
             }
        }else{
             // No records found
        }
    } else {
      //Handle the exception
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That did indeed allow me to access that data! Much appreciated buddy!

Answer (score 1):

do like this

> get every Person object from list and get `PearsonName` from
>   that `Pearson` object

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PersonClass");
query.whereEqualTo("PersonType","human");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> personList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null && personList.size() > 0) {                  
            for (ParseObject person : personList) {
                String pearsonName=personList.getString("PearsonName");
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm too late for answer.but if this helped than you can accept, so it's helpful for other stacky.